# is it common to continue a git branch after merging it?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have a git branch & i want to merge it with my master branch to deliver this phase of my project to product owner.

But i want to continue this branch in future.

It it common to continue a branch after merging it ?

Or i should first delete merged branch and continue the feature with a new branch?

```
git pull 
git merge <my_branch>
git commit 
git push
```

and after a while:

```
git checkout <my_branch>
```

and change it.

Comment: That's fine, with two caveats, one minor and one major. The minor one is to be sure to use `git merge --no-ff` to keep first-parent chaining working (if you don't know what this is, it's something you *may or may not* care about someday in the future, hence "minor"); and: beware of `git merge --squash`.  Squash is not a merge at all, and it makes this particular work-flow problematic.

Comment: @torek ..For some reason, once I merge my feature_branch with main and continue to work on the feature_branch and merge it again with main..The main automatically accepts the incoming changes. Whereas during the first merge...I got an option to either accept the incoming change or not.

Comment: @UmakanthPendyala: *Git* does not have that. Some other program you're using (perhaps via Git as a merge tool, or perhaps atop Git) is giving you that option. You'll be able to find out more about this once you pick apart the parts of your system that *are* (command-line) Git, and the parts that aren't (e.g., are SourceTree, or Eclipse and jgit, or whatever). Note that VSCode, which isn't Git, does have this kind of option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing should stop you from continuing to use the branch. For simplicity with future merges rebasing it off of your master branch may prove useful.

```
git checkout master
git merge feature_branch
git checkout feature_branch
git rebase master (i.e. your branch is now up to date with master)
```

Some good information and diagrams can be found here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows

Comment: for some reason, once I merge my feature_branch with main and continue to work on the feature_branch and merge it again with main..The main automatically accepts the incoming changes. Whereas during the first merge...I got an option to either accept the incoming change or not.